# How does option "Use Step Filter" works in Anylogic debugging?

Tags: debugging, anylogic

Dooes anybody know how to use option "Use Step Filter"  while debugging program? What does it makes and how can help me?

Anylogic help contains such explanation but I don't understand it:
*"Toggles step filters on/off. When on, all step functions apply step filters."*

Read help and read Internet articles...